# How to change an array of hashes by appending a string to a certain value

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I want to convert the following array of hashes:

```
[{:text=>"Code", :url=>"#code"}, {:text=>"Output", :url=>"#output"}]
```

by appending a seed to the URL value:

```
[{:text=>"Code", :url=>"#code1234"}, {:text=>"Output", :url=>"#output1234"}]
```

So far I have this code:

```
- t( :"code.tab" ).each do | obj |

    = obj.collect do | k, v |

        - if k.to_s == "url"
            - [ k, v + seed ].flatten
        - else
            - [ k, v ].flatten
```

Which gives me:

```
[[:text, "Code"], [:url, "#code23324"]][[:text, "Output"], [:url, "#output23324"]]
```

I am close, but I haven't worked-out how to flatten and get the desired result.

Comment: Don't do that sort of transformation in your view. Do it in your controller and pass in a variable you simply iterate over.

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this a bit, can’t you just do `ary.each {|h| h[:url] << seed }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try solving this using `map` on the array and `merge` on the hash:

```
>> a = [{:text=>"Code", :url=>"#code"}, {:text=>"Output", :url=>"#output"}]

>> a.map{|h| h.merge(url: h[:url] + '1234')}
=> [{:text=>"Code", :url=>"#code1234"}, {:text=>"Output", :url=>"#output1234"}]
```

Alternately, you could update your code to turn your results into the desired form by mapping each sub-array into a hash:

```
>> b = [[:text, "Code"], [:url, "#code23324"]], [[:text, "Output"], [:url, "#output23324"]]

>> b.map(&:to_h)
=> [{:text=>"Code", :url=>"#code23324"}, {:text=>"Output", :url=>"#output23324"}]
```